# What is the connection pool library use by JBoss 6.4 EAP?

Tags: jboss, database-connection, datasource, connection-pooling, ironjacamar

I understand previous JBoss versions used [DBCP](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/printer/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html), but I don't find a specific reference to which library and version use JBoss EAP 6.4.

Edit: I found references of uses of [ironjacamar](http://www.ironjacamar.org/) as mentioned by @ehsavoi [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/chap-datasource_management). But I saw this disclaimer:

> "This feature should only be used for development. It is not
> recommended for production environments because it is not supported by
> the JBoss administrative and management tools. This feature is
> deprecated in JBoss EAP 6.4 and will not be supported in the next
> major release of the product."

So my concern is if this disclaimer is related only to datasource deployment (*.ds files) or to ironjacamar as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is using [ironjacamar](http://www.ironjacamar.org/). The version depends on the effective version of EAp 6.4 you are using.

Comment: Yes, I found references to that here https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/chap-datasource_management, but I also saw this disclaimer:
"This feature should only be used for development. It is not recommended for production environments because it is not supported by the JBoss administrative and management tools. This feature is deprecated in JBoss EAP 6.4 and will not be supported in the next major release of the product.", and left me with some concerns about it.

Comment: This feature is using a -ds.xml file to define a datasource instead of using the management model (jboss-cli or hal) to define your datasource in standalone.xml